# how to remove .png image from video file using ffmpeg?

Tags: linux, ffmpeg

trying to convert a .mkv file to .mp4, but in the container is a .png that is causing an error. how do i remove that stream and just convert video and audio? here is the error output

```
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (hevc (native) -> h264 (h264_nvenc))
  Stream #0:8 -> #0:1 (png (native) -> h264 (h264_nvenc))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:2 (dts (dca) -> aac (native))
  Stream #0:2 -> #0:3 (ac3 (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[h264_nvenc @ 0x555781cb73c0] Cannot load libcuda.so.1
Error initializing output stream 0:1 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:1 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
Conversion failed!
```

Comment: What's your full command?

Comment: Avoid `-map 0`?

Comment: it's a bit long `ffmpeg -i /library/movies/Regular Movies/example-Bluray-2160p.mkv -vsync 2 -af loudnorm=I=-16:LRA=11:TP=-1.5 -hide_banner -loglevel info -strict -2 -max_muxing_queue_size 9999 -map_metadata -1 -c:s mov_text -map 0:0 -map 0:8 -map 0:1 -map 0:2 -c:v:0 h264_nvenc -c:v:1 h264_nvenc -c:a:0 aac -c:a:1 aac -y /library/movies/Regular Movies/example-Bluray-2160p.mp4`

Comment: Remove `-map 0:8`. As shown in the error output Stream #0:8 refers to a PNG. However, I will leave this as a comment for now because `Cannot load libcuda.so.1` seems to be an unrelated issue.

Comment: ah. there's no way/command to strip the image so it's not even loaded into the mappings?